# CommandTarget is not working with WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have two  buttons as back and forward and a webbrowser.
I have set CommandTarget as WebBrowser.

```
   <Button Content="Back" Grid.Column="0" Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=AppBrowser}"/>
   <Button Content="Forward" Grid.Column="1" Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=AppBrowser}"/>
```

But the back and forward is not getting enabled/disabled on browser navigation.

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="AppBrowser" extension:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding ElementName=TxtAddress,Path=Text}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the binding to the command.

```
 Command="{Binding NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}"
```